# Using Knex for migrations with Waterline/Sails

Tags: mysql, orm, sails.js, waterline, knex.js

I'm looking at creating a Sails app and am worried about migrations. It seems like there is no real control over them with Waterline.js. Can I use Knex.js to manage migrations? Can someone point me in the right direction with some examples/documentation?

Comment: knex has pretty good documentation with examples etc.
Here is the [link](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations) to migrations section

Comment: Thanks-I was looking for insight on how this would work with Waterline specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Knex for handling migrations on Sails Apps as it it way more reliable then waterline auto-migrate feature (usign mysql)

Regarding your question, and your answer to @coockoo, there is no need to use Knex with waterline, as it works independently.

Just create your migrations with knex, and keep your models updated at api/models/* to reflect your most recent version.

Tip: I created a sails-hook to run migrations on sails Lift, simulating Sails old behavior with auto-migrate